# Please tell me how to open 4d database?

Tags: 4d-database

I trying to open (using 4d v12) the database with the extension .4dc (in addition there are files with extensions .4dd and .4dr).

The result is an error: You cannot convert compiled database. 
Perhaps this is an old version of the database, but I could not find anything that could convert it to a newer version.

My goal is to obtain information from the database. But the problem is that I'm not good at 4d. And I don't know how to open the .4DC as part of an application.

Please help me if you know how to do it.

Comment: Just for the records: 4D keeps all versions (from v11 version of 2008) available online on this freely available ftp server : ftp2-public.4d.fr in the folder /Products/Archives

Answer (score 9):

The .4DC is the compiled structure file. It contains the code of all of your methods and defines the structures (tables, fields) in your database. The .4DD is the actual data file. It contains the values that are stored in the database. The .4DR is the resource file.

You can't edit or convert a .4DC because it is compiled.  What you need is the .4DB. It does the same thing as the .4DC (contains methods and db structure), but you can upgrade it and open it interpreted so you can edit the methods and change the database structure.

You can open the .4DC as part of an application, but you won't be able to upgrade it or edit any methods. If you are opening it with the 4D IDE you'll need the same version as created the .4DC in the first place.

You might also try the 4D knowledgebase for more info: http://kb.4d.com or read the documentation: http://doc.4d.com/Home/home.en.html

Good luck!

Comment: My goal is to obtain information from the database.
But the problem is that I'm not good at 4d. And I don't know how to open the .4DC as part of an application.
Please help me if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

the .4DC is the application, it's only used to run it. As said it's compile in machine language (0 and 1) so it won't help you out. It's good to use the application, that's it.
the .4DD is the actual database behind the application.

So if you want to access only datas, you should look to this .4DD

There are also ODBC drivers that exists for 4D.