# How can I Export Data from 4D Database?

Tags: 4d-database

I'm working with a customer who has a simple application written in [4D database](http://www.4d.com/) stuff from probably 20 or 25 years ago.  They've been using the tool to manage a small portion of their inventory.  As I understand it, that tool in its current form requires a PowerPC operating system.  It's not consistent with current Apple OS.

I was hoping to take a look at the data content, perhaps port it to something else.

The current project's files are: `Acme Co. 2003d.data` (17meg), `Acme Co. 2003e` (3meg), and `.app.zip` (6meg)

I've been looking at the current website for 4D as well as [other similiar postings here in stackoverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331876/please-tell-me-how-to-open-4d-database) or [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938162/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-4d-database)  I'm not seeing anything that remotely resembles that data structure with the suffixes that I have: `.(space)2003d.data` or `.(space)2003e`

Will I be able to use the current 4D software to open the data file and copy the data held within?  Is that even possible?

Comment: Ask the client which version of the software they have installed, then ask the 4D people for a historical version.

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of the files, the current versions available on the website will not open them. Does the customer not have a computer and version that they currently use? That version can export the data using either the quick report editor or the export editor. Or code can be written to perform an export. If not, then an older version would be needed to open the files. That version will not be available on the website. You would need to connect with an experienced developer for that.

Comment: None of that is really clear. The client is 500 miles away and not high tech experienced. He sent the files he believes he is using but the results we're getting don't match what he sees. We can get the 4d app to startup on a PowerPC but we can't get it to link to the data files. Hence my question. What should the file suffixes be?  What files should I be looking for?

Comment: I think what @MacGuido is saying is that your best approach is probably not to get the files directly. But instead to open the 4D application and export the data using the methods he indicates. Then with the data exported to plain text you can do with it what you please.

Comment: That is not what you asked originally. I was unable to find documentation for the suffixes from 20 years ago so I don't know exactly what the suffixes were. The .data suffix is probably the data file. The .2003e suffix is not a valid suffix.  Sounds like you did not get the correct files. Best bet is to use existing software to do what you want.